# Location of the code of the currency switcher

Tags: currency, code

The getSwitchCurrencyUrl() method creates a link like this:

```
http://myshop//directory/currency/switch/currency/USD/uenc/aHR0cDovL...
```

Where can I find the currency switch code which is called when I open the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getSwitchCurrencyUrl()` is exit at `app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Block/Currency.php`

And `Mage_Directory_Helper_Url` class functiona `getSwitchCurrencyUrl`() give  currency change url.

Comment: sorry, it was a missunderstanding. I did not ask where the getSwitchCurrencyUrl() is located, I need to find the code where the new currency will be set when the URL is called.

Comment: Can you check at app/code/core/Directory/controllers/CurrencyController.. SwitchAction

Comment: Thank you, that's it: app/code/core/Mage/Directory/controllers/CurrencyController.php